# Unable to create silverlight project in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

It says

```
You need to install latest Silverlight Developer runtime before creating a Silverlight project.
```

Then gives the following URL:

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060
```

But when I try to install it from here, it says runtime is already installed, and it still won't create the project.

Please help

Comment: Issue may be due to version that the link that Visual Studio was giving was for the 32 bit version, and you may be running 64 bit.Please check your version too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uninstall all "Silverlight..." items in add/remove programs.
2. Install the latest Silverlight SDK, right now it's [Silverlight 5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359)
3. Install Silverlight developer tools which can be found here [Silverlight download sight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight/bb187452.aspx)